# FORD ESCAPE 03 V6 - Oil Light Blinking

Tags: ford, oil, lights, escape

Have a 2003 Escape, oil light started to come in when going down hill in the underground car park where i live but has now started to come on more frequently when braking and today when i pulled up it was blinking on and off, hoping its a new sensor required?

Comment: I'd start with checking the oil level.

Comment: sorry should have mentioned , yes checked this and it was to the higher side of the min max and serviced a month ago

Answer (score 2):

It's important at this point to determine if you really have an oil pressure problem or not.  You really cannot do this with an oil sensor since that simply gives a YES/NO answer.

The next thing you want to do is get an actual oil pressure gauge along with the needed fittings to adapt it to your vehicle and measure the pressure according to the manufacturer's specs in the service procedures.  That will tell you if it's the sensor or a more serious problem.  Note that many auto parts stores lend such tools so check around and see if you can find one available in your area.

If the oil pressure is good, then the problem is your sensor and you should replace it.

If the pressure is not good you are almost certainly looking at some significant engine repair work.   It's likely the oil pump itself that is worn or damaged or the crankshaft rod and crank bearings that are worn and allowing too much oil to leak past them.  With such a leak there is no external evidence of an issue as the oil is not leaking out of the engine itself.

Comment: Will try get my hands on that equipment over next few days but if it’s an oil leak would I not see the levels in the dip decrease or see it leaking below car after it’s parked?

Comment: I'm talking about INTERNAL leaks not external where you would see it dripping or running out.